# c# List<Tuple<string, double>> Foreach in one liner

Tags: c#, foreach, tuples, one-liner

I would like the following code:

```
List<Tuple<string, double>> historicalDailyHigh = new List<Tuple<string, double>>();

  foreach (var item in historicalDailyHigh)
                {
                    if (item.Item1.Contains(closestPreDailyHigh.ToString()))
                    {
                        closestPreDailyHighName = item.Item1;
                    }
                }
```

write in one line, similar to this one, only the "closestPreDailyHighName" should be a string:

```
closestPreDailyHighName = historicalDailyHigh.Any(x => x.Item1.Contains(closestPreDailyHigh.ToString()));
```

can someone give me a tip on how to do this?

Comment: Change `Any` to `FirstOrDefault` to get the `Tuple<string, double>` that matches.

Comment: Note that neither the original way, nor the expected way will return the "closest pre daily highname". The original way will return the **last** value containing the searched text and the expected way will return the **first** value containing the searched text. This means that if you have two or more values containing the searched text, it won't return what you actually want (unless you don't really have any spec about what you want)

Comment: Why do you want it in one line? It's likely going to be harder to read and possibly even slower.

Comment: Anyway if you still would like to iterate through each element that meets the condition, you can try something like this `historicalDailyHigh.Where(h => h.Item1.Contains(closestPreDailyHighName.ToString())).ToList().ForEach(h => closestPreDailyHighName = h.Item1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, your code can be rewritten as

```
 closestPreDailyHighName = historicalDailyHigh
    .LastOrDefault(item => item.Item1.Contains(closestPreDailyHigh.ToString()))
   ?.Item1 ?? closestPreDailyHighName;
```

Note, that you don't put `break` within `if`, that's what it is the *last* item which meets condition will be assigned. If none of `item` meets the condition we don't change the `closestPreDailyHighName`.

If omitting `break` is a *typo*, you can put

```
 closestPreDailyHighName = historicalDailyHigh
    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Item1.Contains(closestPreDailyHigh.ToString()))
   ?.Item1 ?? closestPreDailyHighName;
```

And if there's a *guarantee* that `item` always exists you can change `FirstOrDefault` into `First`:

```
 closestPreDailyHighName = historicalDailyHigh
    .First(item => item.Item1.Contains(closestPreDailyHigh.ToString()))
    .Item1;
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution now looks like this:

```
closestPreDailyHigh = historicalDailyHigh.Min(x => x.Item2);
closestPreDailyHighName = historicalDailyHigh.First(x => x.Item1.Contains(closestPreDailyHigh.ToString())).Item1;
```

thank you for your input!